# Using code in other class

Tags: c#, class, variables, unity-game-engine

My code works perfectly in the player class, but when I try to put it in a different class, it does nothing. My player doesn't lose lifes, and he doesn't die.

Here it doesn't work:

*Spikes class*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spikes : MonoBehaviour
{
  SimplePlayer0 player = new SimplePlayer0();
  Animator anim;
  private bool isDead;

  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
  {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && !isDead && player.Lives <= 1 && !player.IsImmune)
    {
      player.Lives = 0;
      isDead = true;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && player.Lives >= 1 && !player.IsImmune)
    {
      player.Lives--;
      anim.SetBool("Immume", true);
      player.IsImmune = true;
    }
  }




  void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
  {
    if (other.tag == "spike" && !isDead && player.Lives <= 1 && !player.IsImmune)
    {
      player.Lives = 0;
      isDead = true;
    }

    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && player.Lives >= 1 && !player.IsImmune)
    {
      player.Lives--;
      anim.SetBool("Immume", true);
      player.IsImmune = true;
    }
  }


  void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D other)
  {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && !isDead && player.Lives <= 1 && !player.IsImmune)
    {
      player.Lives = 0;
      isDead = true;
    }


    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && player.Lives > 1 && !player.IsImmune)
    {
      player.Lives--;
      anim.SetBool("Immune", true);
      player.IsImmune = true;
    }

    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Underground")
    {
      isDead = true;
    }

  }

  void Dead()
  {
    if (isDead == true)
    {
      Application.LoadLevel(8);
    }
  }

}
```

*Player class*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SimplePlayer0 : MonoBehaviour
{
  Animator anim;



  //Lives
  private int lives = 3;
  private bool isImmune;
  public float immuneCounter;
  public float immuneTime;



  //PROPERTIES

  public int Lives 
  {
    get { return lives; }
    set { lives = value; }
  }

  public bool IsImmune
  {
    get { return isImmune; }
    set { isImmune = value; }
  }


  void Start ()
  {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }

  void Update()
  {

    if (IsImmune)
    {
      immuneCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (immuneCounter <= 0)
    {
      IsImmune = false;
      immuneCounter = immuneTime;     
      anim.SetBool("Immume", false);
    }



}
```

This was the original code where it did work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player0 : MonoBehaviour
{
  Animator anim;


  //Lives
  public int lives = 3;
  public bool isImmune;
  public float immuneCounter;
  public float immuneTime;


  public bool isDead;



  void Start()
  {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }


  void Update()
  {

    if (isImmune)
    {
      immuneCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (immuneCounter <= 0)
    {
      isImmune = false;
      immuneCounter = immuneTime;       
      anim.SetBool("Immume", false);
    }

    if (isDead == true)
    {

      Application.LoadLevel(8);

    }



  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
  {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && !isDead && lives <= 1 && !isImmune)
    {


      rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
      lives = 0;

      rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 200)); // death animation
      isDead = true;


    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && lives >= 1 && !isImmune)
    {
      lives--;
      anim.SetBool("Immume", true);
      isImmune = true;
    }
  }




  void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
  {
    if (other.tag == "spike" && !isDead && lives <= 1 && !isImmune)
    {


      rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
      lives = 0;
      rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 200));
      isDead = true;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && lives >= 1 && !isImmune)
    {
      lives--;
      anim.SetBool("Immume", true);
      isImmune = true;
    }

    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Underground")
    {
      rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 200));
      isDead = true;
    }
  }




  void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D other)
  {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && !isDead && lives <= 1 && !isImmune)
    {
      rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
      lives = 0;

      rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 200));
      isDead = true;


    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "spike" && lives > 1 && !isImmune)
    {
      lives--;
      anim.SetBool("Immune", true);
      isImmune = true;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Underground")
    {
      rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
      lives = 0;


      isDead = true;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: What calls this class? (Btw, the method `Dead` should probably be a player method `IsDead()`)

Comment: Can you show us MonoBehavior? what does it do? Also which parts don't work exactly?

Comment: Why are you instantiating a player object within a class that is designed to kill it? Surely you'd be better off creating the player on start of the scene and just calling methods based on the events you wish to happen? Such as: SomeGameController.playerObject.DecreaseLives(); ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your "Player" doesn't lose lives, because the object you're subtracting the lives from isn't your player. In your Spikes class, you're creating an all new Player object and decreasing the lives from that object, not your already available one.

What I would do, is have a GameController script, which instantiates the player (and anything else that may be required). That way, you know that you've only got one player object to work with.

For example:

```
public static class GameController
{
    public static Player myOnlyPlayer; // either drag in the editor, or instantiate
}
```

Then you can use the following to access the object:

```
public class Spike
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        // Do something with:
        GameController.myOnlyPlayer.ReduceLifeCount();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - instantiating subclasses of `MonoBehaviour` via `new` is an error in itself - I am referring to `SimplePlayer0 player = new SimplePlayer0();` in `Spikes.cs`. Don't do that.

Secondly - LokiSinclair's answer would work, but using a global variable for storing player and always applying the damage to it is very limiting. We should just check for what has collided with spikes and then decide what to do with it (mind you, my code isn't a **really** elegant solution either):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spikes : MonoBehaviour
{
  private void ResolveDamage(Collision2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "player"){
      var player = other.gameObject.getComponent<SimplePlayer0>();
      if(!player.IsImmune){
        player.Lives--;  
      }
    }
  }

  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
  {
    ResolveDamage(other);
  }

  void OnTriggerStay2D(Collision2D other)
  {
    ResolveDamage(other);
  }

  void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D other)
  {
   ResolveDamage(other);
  }
}
```

And your player logic should be contained in Player class - that's just a good design principle to follow:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SimplePlayer0 : MonoBehaviour
{
  Animator anim;

  //Lives
  private int lives = 3;
  private bool isImmune;
  public float immuneCounter;
  public float immuneTime;

  //PROPERTIES


  //putting some logic in getters-setters of your properties
  public int Lives 
  {
    get { return lives; }
    set {
        if(lives != value){
            lives = value;
            if(IsDead){
                Dead();
            }else{
                IsImmune = true;                
            }
        }
    }
  }

  private void Dead()
  {
    Application.LoadLevel(8);
  }

  public bool IsImmune
  {
    get { return isImmune; }
    set { 
        if(isImmune != value){
            isImmune = value; 
            anim.SetBool("Immume", isImmune);
            //ternary operator - a shorthand for if-else statement
            immuneCounter = isImmune ? immuneTime : 0;
        }
    }
  }

  public bool IsDead{
    get{
        return Lives <= 0;
    }
  }

  void Start ()
  {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }

  void Update()
  {
    if (IsImmune)
    {
      immuneCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (immuneCounter <= 0)
    {
      IsImmune = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, so I tried using the code you types , but visual studio keeps telling me there is an error. In the void OnTriggerStay2D method , he gives an error at the part 'ResolveDamage(other);' (The best overload method match for 'Spikes.ResolveDamage(UnityEngine.Collision2D) has some invalid arguments.)
But I don't understand what's wrong with the arguments ? Because the code looks good to me ...

Comment: And at the same place , there's another error:
cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Collider2D' to 'UnityEngine.Collision2D'

Comment: Yep, there was a typo. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, so I already tried what you typed now. And it doesn't give errors , but it still won't work, it doesn't subtract any lifes